# Triple-boot macbook pro (late 2011) with multiple drives

Tags: windows-7, linux, macbook-pro

I own a 15" macbook pro, with a 120GB SSD. I would like to triple-boot (OSX, Windows 7, Linux) due to work reasons. However, due to some lack of foresight on my part, the remaining available space on each partition is nigh unusable (fully updated, windows 7 ultimate takes up close to 32GB of the 40GB partition I gave it).

So, my proposed solution is to get an after market optical bay chassis to hold a second hard disk. Then I will remove the primary hard disk (the SSD) and replace it with the second hard disk.  will install both linux and windows 7 on the new hard disk. Afterwards,  I will remove the optical drive, and move the secondary hard drive to that position, and replace the SSD that contains OSX. Now, will both linux and windows be visible? I know refit doesn't support multiple drive booting, but how about the normal efi boot process? I'm just trying to figure out some way to make this work. Your feedback would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear - resizing the partitions (or migrating to a larger disk and then resizing the partitions) wouldn't help here?  Gparted can very easily resize these, I'd suspect.

Comment: The issue is I am working with a 120GB hard disk, and after installation and patching of each OS in the tri-boot, there is almost no usable space. The primary disk is a SSD, and I'd like to keep it that way (primarily for using OSX). The secondary hard disk would be for linux and windows.

Comment: That's what I figured you would say (that you didn't want to change disks and you were out of space on all three partitions) but I figured it should be made explicit so this didn't have to be any harder than it needed to be.  (PS - disabling hibernation on Windows is likely to free up a good chunk of space, fwiw)

Comment: NP, and good point on the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

They should be visible on an  boot - hold down the  key when you boot the machine, and it should list all available boot volumes.  I know this is the case with external USB drives, and was the case back in the Firewire days...

Comment: Will the linux install show up as Windows? Or will it actually show as linux? If you know that is :)